# Pygame borderless opening with some offset

Tags: python, pygame

When i try to open a borderless mode window it does start in the top right corner of the screen. It looks like this: http://puu.sh/ivB4y/304018da5e.jpg The code looks like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import source.Game, pygame
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(22050, 16, 2, 256)
    pygame.font.init()
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.NOFRAME)
    source.Game.Game().main(screen)
```

It might be worth noting that I'm running two monitors, but I've tried only running one and the problem still happens, and if I take the resolution down below native it still won't start in the top right of my screen.

Is there any way to fix such a problem?

EDIT:

I went this from the answers for anyone looking on this in the future.

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "0,0"
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

along with all the other .init() statements and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want fullscreen:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

You might also want to turn on hardware acceleration adn double buffering using `pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF` if you are running fullscreen.

`display.set_mode` docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode

If you actually want to keep the OS's bar on screen, then instead of going fullscreen, then ideally you would just maximize the window after creating it. However, the version of the SDL lib that Pygame is built on does not support a maximize operation (SDL 2 does). Apparently, you can control the position of the window by setting an environment variable before initializing the window (yuck), but you would still need to figure out the usable area of the desktop. [Example](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/SettingWindowPosition):

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "0,0"

import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. I have a personal taste for borderless mode rather than fullscreen because it makes tabbing out easier and so I'd like to include that in my game. Also when fullscreen is started the screen goes black for a second and all that stuff. Borderless mode is more taxing on the computer from what i hear but it is way better in my opinion and I'd like to give that option. I'm curious if you still recommend double buffer and hardware accel for borderless mode assuming that the borderless mode is 'fullscreen' meaning native resolution?

Comment: Another side note, the taskbar is covered by borderless windows when I do this and that is intentional.

Comment: I'm not sure if using HW accel in a window is a good idea or not in Pygame - I guess you will have to run a stress test of some sort to find out. Maybe try blitting as many sprites as possible, and see if it runs faster with or without acceleration? I've heard that the benefits acceleration are not intuitive, at least in Pygame.